# Why [l[i]] is faster than [v] in python?

Tags: python

I just submit two kind of solutions in an online judging system.

First one is:

```
class Solution:
     # @param S, a list of integer
     # @return a list of lists of integer
     def __init__(self):
         self.res = []

     def _subsets(self, cur, rest):
         if rest == []:
             return
         for i, v in enumerate(rest):
             S = cur[:] + [rest[i]]
             self.res.append(S)
             self._subsets(S, rest[i+1:])

     def subsets(self, S):
         S.sort()
         self._subsets([], S)

         self.res.append([])
         return self.res
```

Second one is:

```
 class Solution:
     # @param S, a list of integer
     # @return a list of lists of integer
     def __init__(self):
         self.res = []

     def _subsets(self, cur, rest):
         if rest == []:
             return
         for i, v in enumerate(rest):
             S = cur[:] + [v]
             self.res.append(S)
             self._subsets(S, rest[i+1:])

     def subsets(self, S):
         S.sort()
         self._subsets([], S)

         self.res.append([])
         return self.res
```

There is only one difference. In the forth line of function `_subsets`, the first one is `S = cur[:] + [rest[i]]` and the second one is `S = cur[:] + [v]`.

I'm pretty sure that `[rest[i]]` is slower than `[v]`. And I have used function `dis.dis` to check the bytecodes of them. It leads to the same conclusion. However, why the first version is faster then the second one? Do I miss something?

Comment: I suspect your test methodology. The first one demonstrably does more work than the second (it has to call `rest.__getitem__` where the second does not), and even with that difference there shouldn't be a significant difference in speed.

Comment: Not related to the question, but `cur[:]` should not be needed here, as `cur + [whatever]` already creates a shallow copy of `c` (assuming those are regular Python lists).

Comment: they should be effectively the same ... how are you timing this ...

Comment: The cost time is given by the online judge system of leetcode. Is this a bug of that online judge system?